# Load CPS project in integrated shell

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-shell, common-project-system

I have a custom language and debug editor extension for Visual studio, that I'd like to be able to distribute using the visual studio integrated shell.

However, I am unable to open the custom project files using the integrated shell application:

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
     - scripts, "F:\path\to\example.myproj"


No changes required
These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
     - scripts, "F:\path\to\example.Example_sln"
```

Everything works fine when the extension is loaded as part of visual studio 2015 directly.

The custom project type was created using [The Visual Studio Common Project System](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user rodya0 on Github, I have [an answer](https://github.com/Microsoft/VSProjectSystem/issues/140#issuecomment-314327023):

Add the following:

```
$ShellFolder$\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\Project; \
```

to the `PkgDefSearchPath` section of the .pkgdef file in your isolated shell project